# How to resolve Unexpected token, expected during import module in nodejs

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I don't see where is my error in this code, can you help me?
import app from "../app";
^^^^^^

I had add this `"type": "module"` in my package.json but my server stop to run.

```
const request = require("supertest");
import app from "../app";



describe("Test the root path", () => {
  test("It should response the GET method", () => {
    return request(app).get('/').then((res) => {
        expect(res.statusCode).toBe(200);
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: I think you can't use `require` with `"type": "module"`, Node returns the following error: `ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead`, also you are missing the `.js` extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't use ES6 module with "type": module setting together with CommonJs which use require, so pick one you prefer :

CommonJs :

```
const request = require("supertest");
const app = require("../app.js");
```

ES module:

```
import request from 'supertest'; // supertest should now support ES6.
import app from "../app.js";
```